# Encrypt a message for one other person to read

Tags: javascript, encryption

I have a need to encrypt a message for just one other person to read, I have the other person's public key and I have my own public and private key stored in a UTC Keystore.

The keys were generated using webpacked functions from ethereumjs-util.

Please could you suggest the best method to write two functions that encrypt and decrypt.

The encrypt will takes the other person's public key along with the message and return an unreadable buffer or string

The decrypt will take the other person's private key and the encrypted string/buffer and return a plain text of the message

Comment: is this to be done on a browser? If so, **don't** ... you'll expose your private key, rendering it useless

Comment: The user can enter a private key into the browser without it being transmitted over the wire

Comment: oh, OK, hadn't considered having a private key entered interactively :p

Comment: You wouldn't use your own key to encrypt a message for another person, you'd use only that person's public key, then they'd use their private key to decrypt it. (If you also want to sign the message, *then* you'd use your own private key and they'd use your public key to confirm the signature.)

Comment: It seems like there are 2 processes that I've confused into one. Signing proves the message has come from me, and Encrypting ensures only the other person can read it. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

there are a few [libraries](https://gist.github.com/jo/8619441) for that

as well note PKI (public key crypto) is having limit in data to encrypt, so youay want to read about [hybrid cryptosystem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem)